# Swap text for a Drawable image

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

The code contains an alternating "Play" and "Pause" button. It works fine, but would it be possible to customize them with a Drawable image?

I've tried using

```
btControl.getCompoundDrawables(R.id.imgplay)
```

but I did not succeed.

```
if (btControl.getText().equals("►")) {

                this.startService(intent);
                cmPasstime.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                cmPasstime.start();
                btControl.setText("■");


            } else if (btControl.getText().equals("■")) {
                this.stopService(intent);
                cmPasstime.stop();
                btControl.setText("►");


            } else if (btControl.getText().equals("►")) {
                this.startService(intent);
                cmPasstime.start();
                btControl.setText("■");
            }
```

Is there any way to insert two images in place of "►" and "■"?

Comment: are you using drawable image as a background for button ?

Comment: @Umair  yes, background with an image and text set with "►". Only with the image does not work.

Comment: @CinthiaDanielle you mean with image it crashes ? If yes then can you share your logs ? If no then have you tried changing background as 
`button.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.play);
            }`

Comment: It is good to use two different button with the different ID and make their visibility Visible and Gone according to your need. By doing this you can easily maintain it and can use drawable background too..

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to set tag to button as identifier and take decision on its value instead of getting drawable. Like

```
  if (((String)btControl.getTag()).equals("playing")) {


        btControl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paused);
        btControl.setTag("paused");

        // Your Code


    } else if (((String)btControl.getTag()).equals("paused")) {

        btControl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playing);
        btControl.setTag("playing");

        // Your Code

    }
```